# onDoubleTap decreases performance in GestureDetector without generate event

Tags: flutter, dart, gesturedetector

**Expected results:**

I don't expect a difference in performance if I don't double tap.

**Actual results:**

I added the double tap event and noticed that by simply adding it, the performance of the application is greatly diminished.
If, on the other hand, I comment the line, then the performance returns stable.

If I had created any performance problems I would expect them if I double tap.
But just add the event line that the performances drop drastically.

**Code**

```
void _startOperation(BuildContext ctx) {
_timer = Timer(const Duration(milliseconds: 150), () {
  isLongPressed = true;
  if (!widget.cell.isShowed) {
    Provider.of<GameModelProvider>(ctx, listen: false).setFlag(widget.cell);
    HapticFeedback.mediumImpact();
  }
});
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return GestureDetector(
  onDoubleTap: () => Provider.of<GameModelProvider>(context, listen: false)
      .speedOpenCell(widget.cell),
  onTapDown: (_) {
    _startOperation(context);
  },
  onTapUp: (_) {
    if (!isLongPressed) {
      Provider.of<GameModelProvider>(context, listen: false)
          .computeCell(widget.cell);
    } else {
      isLongPressed = false;
    }
    _timer.cancel();
  },
  child: Container(
    width: widget.cellWidth,
    height: widget.cellHeight,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: widget.cell.isShowed
          ? Colors.grey.shade300
          : Colors.grey.shade400,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
    ),
    child: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
      child: Center(
        child: getContent(),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

You get all code here : https://github.com/EliaTolin/infinity_sweeper

Answer (score 0):

It’s not that the performance has changed there is just latency because the flutter framework now has to wait (300ms) to determine if the gesture is actually a double tap versus a single tap.